# R : how copy (last) column name to new column as values?

Tags: r

In short, I need to  create new column with timestamps, taking from another column name

So I have already  this command to select below columns from dataset : `Lat, Long_, last_col()`
I use last(col) because column  name (date) is changing

```
data_new <- data %>%
  select(Lat, Long_, last_col() )
```

Results:

```
"Lat","Long_","5/26/20"
-14.271,-170.132,44
13.4443,144.7937,167
```

My goal is to achieve below results:

```
"Lat","Long_","date","Value"
-14.271,-170.132,"5/26/20",44
13.4443,144.7937,"5/26/20",167
```

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
data_new %>%
     mutate(date = names(.)[3]) %>%
     rename(Value = `5/26/20`)
```

---

If there are more rows, then the bug free approach is `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(data_new, cols = -c(Lat:Long_), names_to = 'date')
```